# Reduce space used by QComboBox / avoid text truncation

Tags: c++, qt

In a Application building on Qt (5.2), I'm using `QComboBox`es for showing some values the user can select from.

The controls are there in the .ui file already, but empty. In my application, I add a few  values to them programmatically. Since I want to show multiple QComboBox elements in one line, they shouldn't take up too much space, so I set their maximum width.

By default, they however seem to have some strange truncation or a required "empty space" between the selected text on the left and the "down" arrow on the right. When I make the size of the QComboBox smaller with maximum width, the selected text will be truncated (even though there would be plenty of space for showing the full text). It looks like this:

[image]

The selected text (100) was already selected before opening the dropdown, so the text at the top should read 100, but because of this strange truncation effect it only reads "10" (I verified that several times that the actually selected string is "100" - it's only the display that's truncated somehow).

Where does this truncation / empty space come from? Can I prevent it from happening - or remove this empty space - somehow? I checked all the QComboBox properties, but couldn't find anything which could apply, and also tried searching for this on the net, but apparently I had the wrong search terms, as I haven't yet found anyone having this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're encountering Qt's default size issues. I've had this with a few different widgets.
Qt applies a quite generous default padding. There is a way to get around this with a style.  (IE, make it tighter). To completely remove the inner padding of the `QComboBox`, you can do this:

```
// given a QComboBox *myComboBox;
myComboBox->setStyleSheet("padding: 0");
```

Comment: I would have no problem with truncation, if it was (a) indicated somehow (like the ... you mention) and (b) not truncated far too early ( why leave >~20px completely free?) the current truncation is indeed very weird, It seems rather there is something overlaying the actual text or something. Any hints on how to do this styling you are talking about? I'll try the programmatic sizing for now...

Comment: I've had issues like this with a few widgets.  Qt has some default padding for just about everything, and I did not really like it in some cases.  Look into QStyle (I think) which is basically applying a CSS style to a widget.  This is apparently revamped from I think 4.6 to 4.8 (and maybe more in 5?).

Comment: Hm If I read the description in the [QStyle class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#details) correctly, this class to me seems only responsible for the look and feel of the controls, but not for any specific css styles?

Comment: I've now found how to add stylesheets (duh, QWidget::setStyleSheet, quite obvious), but i wouldn' even begin to know *what* I should style, since I don't know what is going on (i.e. if there is something obstructing the view on the text that I'd need to remove, or what element I'd have to make bigger for the text to be shown - it's obviosuly not the QComboBox as a whole...) any hints?

Comment: ah yes! padding was the culprit apparently. Doing `setStyleSheet("padding: 0")` did the trick. Since you were guiding me in the right direction, I'll add that to your answer and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks!  Glad that it was a help.  Would have commented/added more earlier but was away from the interwebs for the weekend.